# Resize images based on another image in html5/css3

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm trying to re-size an image based on different image.

I have a background image, the image is resizing when you small the browser or open the web site on smaller/bigger screen size. But other images don't resize when the background getting smaller or bigger.

Look: [www.taylanmiroglu.com/ninniline/v1.0](http://www.taylanmiroglu.com/ninniline/v1.0)

When your mouse come at the woman and pillow, you can see the new images with an animation (on my computer resolution)

When you small your browser, background image perfectly getting smaller with same ratio, but the images (women and pillow) don't get smaller with the same ratio as background.

I want them to be resized with using background resize ratio.

For example; if background get 97% smaller than original size, the other images must be smaller too with the same ratio which is 97% for this example.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much, I have been searching it for 6 hours but nothing so far.

Codes of whole page:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/arka_plan.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#manken {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:260px;
    opacity:0;



    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#manken:hover {
    opacity:1;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#yastik {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:350px;
    margin-left:665px;
    opacity:0;



    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#yastik:hover {
    opacity:1;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

<body>
<div id="manken"><img src="images/manken.png"></div>
<div id="yastik"><img src="images/yastik.png"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: As far as i know, that won't be posible using only CSS if  the background-size is cover; unless the images have the same ratio

Comment: Well, okay then do you know any way to do that? I open for any suggestion. With Javascript etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have set the 'cover' background-size property as a javascript function.
Then, the main image is on an element that gets resized and centered with that function.

The other elements are in this base element, and get resized/repositioned automatically

```js
function resizeContent() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('container');
  var height = ele.clientHeight;
  var width = ele.clientWidth;
  var innerWidth = 1432;
  var imageHeight = 703;
  var scaleH = width /innerWidth;
  var scaleV = height / imageHeight;
  var scale = Math.max (scaleH, scaleV);

  var ele2 = document.getElementById('base');
  ele2.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";

  var top = (height - imageHeight) / 2;
//  top = Math.min (top, 0);
  ele2.style.top = top + "px";

  var left = (width - innerWidth) / 2;
//  left = Math.min (left, 0);
  ele2.style.left = left + "px";
}
 
// Function to add event listener
window.onload = function () { 
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeContent, false); 
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative;
}
#base { 
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FUus.jpg); 
  width: 1432px;
  height: 703px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#manken {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 17.6%;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#manken:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

#yastik {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 49%;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#yastik:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="base">
<div id="manken"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vizpy.png"></div>
<div id="yastik"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBlhs.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: base]
[image: manken]
[image: yastik]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using transform property that css provides..?? It might be of some help.

you could maybe try visiting this:

http://codingtips.kanishkkunal.in/zoom-effect-image-css/

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty basic solution, but have you tried making the 2 smaller images canvas' the same size as the large background? If you line the elements up with their matching section on the large background, and then make the rest of the background transparent...

So basically you have 3 images the same size, however 2 of them are just the cut-out objects with the rest transparent. Therefore scaling down the display would scale the images at the same ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But main idea is here, when the mouse come over the woman or pillow, the images will be emphasized. So if I have 3 same size images, the images which is woman and pillow always be emphasized, not only the mouse come over the woman or pillow.

Comment: Yeah I see. I don't know the specifics of your project, so this might not _work_. Maybe having the 3 images one after the other _in the background_, and using other divs to capture the hover, that fade the correct layer in - targeting necessary div that contains that image with some jQuery maybe. Would something like that work?